# Getting error message unknown server tag 'dnn:ComboBox' when setting staging from production

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke

I have copied files and database from production environment and copied to staging server, when I browsed on staging environment then getting this error message. 
[image]

Comment: What namespace is `dnn`? Sounds like it's a third-party control suite, and if that's the case then you're likely missing a reference to it locally in your code, or it's a GAC-based library and you need to install it onto the server too.

Comment: DNN(DotNetNuke) is an open source CMS tool used for creating dynamic pages and modules.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely occurs because you're missing the referenced assemblies on the server. The DotNetNuke libraries appear to be missing.

You need to add the relevant references as [`CopyLocal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.100).aspx) and then redeploy.

It's a good idea to ensure that your environments are as near-identical as possible, and that if referencing third-party libraries, you're either:

1. Installing the libraries in the GAC across all environments and referencing from the GAC
2. Using copy-local references and deploying the assemblies with your code
3. Using something like Nuget and having your CI system resolve them prior to deployment.

Comment: Hi, I have copied all files from bin folder without overwriting it in staging to preserve their version details.

Comment: @ravichandra are the DotNetNuke assemblies there? What sort of reference is in your project?

Comment: Yes DNN assemblies is there.

Comment: @ravichandra how are they referenced in the project? Can you post a screenshot of the reference in visual studio?

Comment: dotnetnuke is CMS

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing your development web.config file with staging. I guess you have a tagprefix (e.g. < add tagprefix="dnn".. />) in your development config file (under system.web -> pages -> controls) but not in staging.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an incomplete backup/restore. Please start over. Be sure to copy all files. If they're coming from a Zip file, be sure to "unblock" the Zip file in its properties.

A good backup restore will have the following:

1. All files from the original location (sometimes in a zip file).
2. Full backup of the database.

A good restore requires the following:

- Domain name to respond to.
- A folder with the full file system backup copied into it.
- The folder will require permissions to load all files (e.g., `IIS_IUSRS` and `Network Service`).
- Full restore of the database to an accessible (local?) database with a unique user assigned to it as `db_owner`.
- Updated web.config to reflect the new database location and user credentials (usually requires at least 1-2 updates).
- Update the `PortalAlias` and `PortalSettings` tables to correctly reflect the website domain name to respond to (e.g., `localhost.mysite` instead of `productiondomain.com`).

As long as there are no typos or missed steps, this works every time.

Optional additional things that we usually do include:

- Scanning for viruses.
- Scanning for unexpected files (e.g., *.asp and *.php).
- Updating the `HostSettings` to reflect a new (local SMTP) server.
- Cleansing the restored database of PII.